# Error monad in Python - did I do it right?

Tags: python, monads

Questions:

- Is this a monad?
- does this demonstrate a reasonable understanding of error monad?
- what am I missing?
- what else can I do with this code to flex monads more?
- i'm confused as to the relation of success/fail to "return"/"result"/"lift" (i think these are all the same concepts).
- how can we make the problem more complex, such that monads help us solve our pain points? monads help here because we abstracted away the `if result != None` plumbing, what other types of plumbing might I want to abstract, and how do monads (or 'monad combinators') help this pain?

I'm a bit underwhelmed.

```
# helpers for returning error codes
def success(x): return (True, x)
def fail(x): return (False, x)

# bind knows how to unwrap the return value and pass it to
# the next function
def bind(mv, mf):
    succeeded = mv[0]
    value = mv[1]

    if (succeeded): return mf(value)
    else: return mv

def lift(val): return success(val)

def userid_from_name(person_name):
    if person_name == "Irek": return success(1)
    elif person_name == "John": return success(2)
    elif person_name == "Alex": return success(3)
    elif person_name == "Nick": return success(1)
    else: return fail("No account associated with name '%s'" % person_name)

def balance_from_userid(userid):
    if userid == 1: return success(1000000)
    elif userid == 2: return success(75000)
    else: return fail("No balance associated with account #%s" % userid)

def balance_qualifies_for_loan(balance):
    if balance > 200000: return success(balance)
    else: return fail("Insufficient funds for loan, current balance is %s" % balance)

def name_qualifies_for_loan(person_name):
    "note pattern of lift-bind-bind-bind, we can abstract further with macros"
    mName =    lift(person_name)
    mUserid =  bind(mName, userid_from_name)
    mBalance = bind(mUserid, balance_from_userid)
    mLoan =    bind(mBalance, balance_qualifies_for_loan)

    return mLoan

for person_name in ["Irek", "John", "Alex", "Nick", "Fake"]:
    qualified = name_qualifies_for_loan(person_name)
    print "%s: %s" % (person_name, qualified)
```

output:

```
Irek: (True, 1000000)
John: (False, 'Insufficient funds for loan, current balance is 75000')
Alex: (False, 'No balance associated with account #3')
Nick: (True, 1000000)
Fake: (False, "No account associated with name 'Fake'")
```

Comment: Very nice question. I think the code is okay as it is, but it could be spiced up a lot by overloading the `>>` operator and using lambdas. A totally different approach is the one from [here](http://www.valuedlessons.com/2008/01/monads-in-python-with-nice-syntax.html), that guy uses decorators and `yield` to make this almost look right :)

Comment: I restructured that code slightly to make it more readable. Hope you don't mind (and if you do, please roll it back :)

Answer (score 3):

**Is this a monad?** See the [monad laws](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monad_Laws):

> All instances of the Monad class should obey:
>
> 1. "Left identity":
>      return a >>= f  ≡  f a
> 2. "Right identity":
>      m >>= return  ≡  m
> 3. "Associativity":
>      (m >>= f) >>= g  ≡  m >>= (\x -> f x >>= g)

*(`return` means success, `>>=` means bind)*

1. Left identity.  In your implementation, this could be:

   ```
   bind(success(x), balance_qualifies_for_loan) == balance_qualifies_for_loan(x)
   ```

   where `x` is some value and `f` is a monadic function.
2. Right identity.  Again, this could be:

   ```
   bind(m, success) == m
   ```

   where `m` is a monadic value.
3. Associativity.  This could be:

   ```
   bind(bind(m,  userid_from_name), balance_from_userid)) ==
     bind(m, lambda x: bind(userid_from_name(x), balance_from_userid))
   ```

All of these could be written as unit tests to quickly check that these properties hold for many input values.

**What is missing?**

- each monad needs a different implementation of `success` and `bind`.  Putting these into an interface would allow you to write code generic over all implemented monads.
- based on [the Haskell approach](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#t%3aMonad), you might want to implement some general monad combinators, such as `>>`, `sequence` and `mapM`.  These make monads very convenient to use.

Comment: can you extend my problem such that monad combinators help me solve it? I guess I'm trying to understand what sort of pain points one might have that monads help solve.